# CUDA .Net compare strings

Tags: c#, .net, cudafy.net

I'm trying to compare lists of strings (huge amount of elements in each of lists). Could somebody help me to do it using [cudafy](http://cudafy.codeplex.com/)? I guess that in that case I should use jagged arrays of char but I've got an CudafyCompileException - expression must have class type ([tried this approach](http://cudafy.codeplex.com/discussions/284797)). It worked just for two strings (char[]). So any ideas how I can do that?

Code sample for 2 strings:

```
var km = CudafyTranslator.Cudafy();
_gpu = CudafyHost.GetDevice();
_gpu.LoadModule(km);
var strFirst = "Hello, world";
var strSecond = "Hi world";
var devResult = _gpu.Allocate<char>(strFirst.Length);
var first = strFirst.ToCharArray();
var second = strSecond.ToCharArray();
var result = new char[strFirst.Length];
var devFirst = _gpu.CopyToDevice(first);
var devSecond = _gpu.CopyToDevice(second);
_gpu.Launch(N, 1).CompareStrings(devFirst, devSecond, devResult);
_gpu.CopyFromDevice(devResult, result);
var hostStr = new string(result);
Console.WriteLine(hostStr);
```

And the method itself:

```
[Cudafy]
public static void CompareStrings(GThread thread, char[] c, char[] b, char[] result)
{
    int tid = thread.blockIdx.x;
    if (tid < c.Length)
    {
        if (c[tid] == b[tid])
        {
            result[tid] = c[tid];
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- instead c.Length pass the length as a parameter
- be careful if you useing Unicode character, that 2 bytes